# "Definition could not be found" при импорте класса fl.controls.ComboBox в actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript

Нужно создать стандартный элемент `ComboBox` на сцене в файле `as`. При импорте класса `fl.controls.ComboBox` возникает ошибка

> "1172: Definition fl.controls:ComboBox could not be found."

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась так:
"Во вложении правильный, там все компоненты из fl.
А сделать его проще простого, надо во flash cs3 - 4
нажать ctrl+F7 ctrl+L
и перетянуть все компоненты в библиотеку.
нажать ctrl+shift+F12 на вкладке flash поставить галочку export swc и ctrl+enter
флешки созданные во flash cs3 - сs4 не часть коммерческого продукта, значит и swc созданные в нем-же не есть его частью."
http://www.flasher.ru/forum/showthread.php?p=831798